# Getting the Session Token out of the Response of Parse Rest API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, curl, parse-platform

I'm following the https://parse.com/docs/rest/guide for logging in users. My question is: How do I get the current logged in user?

This is my code so far:

```
class LoginController < ApplicationController
  def index

  end
  def log_in

    headers = {"X-Parse-Application-Id" => "API_KEY", 
                         "X-Parse-REST-API-Key" => "API_KEY"}
    query = {:username => params[:user][:username], 
                     :password => params[:user][:password]}

            @response = HTTParty.get('https://api.parse.com/1/login', 
        :query => query,
            :headers => headers)
   end
end
```

The `@response` returns user information along with session token which is new everytime I refresh the browser? Is that right? Also if it is correct, how to I get the session token out of the @response so I can use it for later REST API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@response` is a Hash and you can get `sessionToken` from it

```
@response["sessionToken"]
```

If you inspect `@response` using `p @response`, you will see something like below:

```
#<HTTParty::Response:0x2d56590 parsed_response={"createdAt"=>"2015-08-01T10:11:38.439Z", "objectId"=>"ZLIk9hKmki", "phone"=>"12345-67890", "sessionToken"=>"r:RIWzQiY3kGhRPDtaLmjDizZog", "updatedAt"=>"2015-08-01T10:11:38.439Z", "username"=>"some_user_id"}, @response=#<Net::HTTPOK 200 OK readbody=true>, @headers={"access-control-allow-methods"=>["*"], "access-control-allow-origin"=>["*"], "content-type"=>["application/json; charset=utf-8"], "date"=>["Sun, 02 Aug 2015 12:58:39 GMT"], "server"=>["nginx/1.6.0"], "x-parse-platform"=>["G1"], "x-runtime"=>["0.136318"], "content-length"=>["191"], "connection"=>["Close"]}>
```

So, you can access other attributes as well by doing the following

```
p @response["phone"]
p @response["username"]
```

Comment: can you help me on this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31851606/updating-a-column-parse-rest-api/31864171#31864171