# updating a column Parse Rest API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, curl, parse-platform

i am trying to update a Users information for ex. Phone, email etc.

i looked at this: https://parse.com/docs/rest/guide#users-updating-users

so i wrote this in my controller:

```
@response = HTTParty.put('https://api.parse.com/1/users/',
  :headers => {"X-Parse-Application-Id" => "APIKEY", 
               "X-Parse-REST-API-Key" => "APIKEY",
               "X-Parse-Session-Token" => session[:session_token],
               "Content-Type" => "application/json"},
  :data    => {"phoneNumber" => "9994432"})
```

I return `@response` in a view and get back this: 
`{"error"=>"requested resource was not found"}`

I was thinking maybe its because im not passing the user's objectid in the url?

Comment: Well, why don't you add objectID and see the result? :)

Comment: i added it and im getting this `{"code"=>107, "error"=>"invalid JSON"}` also how do i add it dynamically, i dont want to hard code it obviously, i want it so which ever user is using the site

Comment: in your Application-Id-Header the value says "APIKEY", same as REST-API-Key - maybe a typo only, but it wouldn't work with the same key for both headers.

Answer (score 0):

Well, now that you have played with creating HTTP requests to API manually, it's time to switch to some library/gem for interactions with Parse. Hopefully, people who built the library that you will find, already have dealt with many routine tasks (like formatting your JSON properly – the error you are investigating right now), and have good documentation for many cases.

I suggest [parse-ruby-client](https://github.com/adelevie/parse-ruby-client).

Add `gem 'parse-ruby-client', github: 'adelevie/parse-ruby-client'` to Gemfile (it's better to use `master` version, not the current Rubygems version, because they are saying that there are some useful changes which are not yet pushed to Rubygems), then run `bundle install` as usual, and you are good to go.

Object saving is as easy as

```
game_score = client.object("GameScore")
game_score["score"] = 1337
game_score["playerName"] = "Sean Plott"
game_score["cheatMode"] = false
result = game_score.save
puts result
```

according to their [documentation](https://github.com/adelevie/parse-ruby-client#creating-objects).

**UPD**. Answering original question. You can use a function to provide object id dynamically:

```
def update_user(object_id)
  @response = HTTParty.put("https://api.parse.com/1/users/#{object_id}",
    :headers => {"X-Parse-Application-Id" => "APIKEY", 
           "X-Parse-REST-API-Key" => "APIKEY",
           "X-Parse-Session-Token" => session[:session_token],
           "Content-Type" => "application/json"},
    :data => {"phoneNumber" => "9994432"})
end
```

Comment: i cant do it with the Parse Rest API?

Comment: This gem does use Parse Rest API. Of course you can do anything you wish with HTTParty only. But you suffered enough, time to move on to more suitable instruments for your task at hand :)

Comment: how can i pass the object id in the http request url?

Comment: if you still want to use HTTParty after all I said: it seems that you must add it to the end of the URL

Comment: yes i realize that but how can i do it so its a variable so that whoever is logged in will be dynamic

Comment: well, you can make a function, which will take user id as an argument and add it to the string, and then call that function

Comment: so i can do object_id = session[:objectId]?

Comment: Yep, or you could just use `session[:objectId]` in the string itself: `"https://api.parse.com/1/users/#{session[:objectId}"`

Comment: getting this: `bad URI(is not URI?): https://api.parse.com/1/users/#{session[:object_id]}`

Comment: *Sigh*. Use double quotes: `"string"`:) Single quotes – `'string'` don't support interpolation (i.e. inserting variables with `#{...}` syntax).

Comment: yea i figured that out, so now i get this now. {"code"=>107, "error"=>"invalid JSON"} heres my request. `@res = HTTParty.put("https://api.parse.com/1/users/#{object_id}",
    :headers => {"X-Parse-Application-Id" => "APIKEY", 
               "X-Parse-REST-API-Key" => "APIKEY",
               "X-Parse-Session-Token" => session[:session_token],
               "Content-Type" => "application/json"},
    :data    => {"phoneNumber" => "9994432"})`

Comment: Where did you get `:data` key from? It should be `:body`, shouldn't it?

Comment: you also forgot to add `#to_json` to your hash: `{"phoneNumber" => "9994432"}.to_json`

Comment: ahhh `{"code"=>101, "error"=>"object not found for update"`} but i have the column there...

Comment: do you know whats going on?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85394/discussion-between-user3670235-and-eugzol).

Answer (score 0):

My solution is force the variables to int and string

```
response = HTTParty.put("https://api.parse.com/1/users/#{object_id}",
:headers => {
        "X-Parse-Application-Id" => ENV['PARSE_APP_ID'].to_s, 
        "X-Parse-REST-API-Key" => ENV['PARSE_API_KEY'].to_s,
        "X-Parse-Session-Token" => token.to_s,
        "Content-Type" => "application/json"},
  :body => {"h_optimum" => optimum.to_i,
        "h_moderate" => moderate.to_i,
        "h_appalling" => appalling.to_i}
)
```